# Grouping/clustering graph edges with same color in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have a digraph in D3 v4 where edges of the same "group" number (assigned in the associated JSON) are displayed with the same color.  I am trying to make the edges with the same color appear adjacent to each other when the graph is loaded.

I have tried changing D3's link forces, but I'm not sure if they are the right parameters to tweak for this task (is it possible to have edges with positive affinity for a certain group but negative for the rest?).  I also looked at examples where nodes were clustered (such as [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887), and [here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/circularpacking_group.html)), but I don't know if the parameters applied to nodes can be applied to edges.  I've had a lot of trouble finding approaches to the problem I'm having.

I am declaring my forceSimulation as such:

```
let force = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
              .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
              .force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.edges))
              .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(w/2).y(h/2));
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Thegreatmochi/uaLs8qm1/5/) with the full graph.

Comment: do you have a constant central node, like in your jsfiddle?  if not, and the coloured links can go from any node to any node, then the grouping links going out from any node will be hard with D3

Comment: @TomShanley, can you elaborate on what you mean by 'central node'? Is it in terms of positioning, or forces (I understand those might be the same thing)?  I see how my main question may be confusing for the general case, though. For my problem, colored links indeed do not necessarily go to a main (green in this context) node, they may go to other nodes.  I can illustrate with another graph later if that helps.

Comment: in the jsfiddle, node 0 seems to be central node, and the colour links would be best ordered around that node. if this is the case, you could position node 0 in the centre of the chart, and then for nodes with blue links place top-right, orange at bottom-right, and black to the left. but this really only works if the graph as a central node

Answer (score 0):

[`forceLink.strength`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_strength) can be used in order to specify a link strength according to the data.

A variable can be created to store the desired link strength by group, and then be used in the `.strength` function, as shown below.

```
let strengthByGroup = [.5, 1, .1]

.force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.edges)
            .strength(function(d) {
              return strengthByGroup[d.group]
            })
)
```

Demo in the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ky5gefrn/).

For more precise control about links physical location, `forceLink.distance` may be used as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi, this is an interesting idea however does not exactly solve my problem.   As you can see the orange edges are now extended and not exactly clustered together.  I was wondering if edges can have different strength depending on the edge:  high affinity for those in the same group, low for those that aren't, but that just may not be possible in this context.

Comment: This is not clear. Nodes attract and repulse each other, not edges. Usually, nodes are in groups, not edges. You may want to adapt your data structure accordingly. Could you edit the question to reformulate what the expectation is, and possibly give a mockup image illustrating the desired effect?